# two facebook canvas apps, one user, two different user ids. Why?

Tags: facebook, userid

I have created 2 facebook apps, hosted in the same external domain. I have installed these two apps in a facebook page of mine and in both apps i am running the following php code at the beginning:

```
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

// start session

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxx','yyy' );

// login helper with redirect_uri

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('https://apps.facebook.com/my_namespace/' );

try 
{
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} 
catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) 
{
  // When Facebook returns an error
}
catch( Exception $ex ) 
{
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) 
{
    // graph api request for user data
    $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
    $response = $request->execute();
    // get response
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

    // print data
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
} 
else 
{
    // show login url
    echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '" target="_top">Login</a>';
}
```

When I run each application, the user identity that is shownn is equal for all properties except for user id:

One app 1, i see:

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object
```

(
    [backingData:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1400416826952138
            [email] => my_name@gmail.com
            [first_name] => Name
            [gender] => female
            Etc

On app 2 I see:

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object
```

(
    [backingData:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1397126750614479
            [email] => my_name@gmail.com
            [first_name] => Name
            [gender] => female
            Etc

As i am using the same user (my account) in both apps, why are there 2 different ID for the same user account?

Thanks

Nat

Comment: Because they are app scoped user ids. I suggest reading the documentation about it

Comment: Thank you for the tip! the "app scoped user ids" were the key words i was missing to understand all this problem